# VS2022 unable to publish to Azure my net48 MVC web app, to anything other than Target Runtime = Portable

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2022, webdeploy, .net-4.8

I have a .Net 4.5.1 MVC web application which I used the upgrade assistant to upgrade to .Net 4.8. I had to manually fix quite a few thing, but it now works fine if I run it locally via IIS Express.

It previously published okay to Azure in VS2019 (via a right click from the solution explorer).

But publishing it to Azure from VS2022 only gives me the option of Target Runtime = Portable, with nothing else in the dropdown. E.g. no win-x86, win-x64.  [see attached]

[image]

How do I go back to being able to publish normally as I did in VS2019? Or is this intended? Can I only publish my net48 web application to Portable?

---

**NOTE**: I created a new publish profile by importing the publish profile from Azure, and it does the same thing.

If I hack my publish profile & add net6.0, then right-click publish from VS2022, it does populate the Target Runtime dropdown with the targets I am expecting to see, e.g.  Portable, win-x86, win-x64, win-arm ...

But obviously I can't publish like this, as it is a net48 app.

Answer (score 0):

> But publishing it to Azure from VS2022 only gives me the option of Target Runtime = Portable, with nothing else in the dropdown. E.g., no win-x86, win-x64. [see attached]

Before publishing the .NET 4.8.x Web Application to the Azure App Service from any IDE, you can edit the Platform Setting option from Azure Portal by going to your *Web App > Configuration > General Settings > Change Platform* to the required configuration Such as 32-bit or 64-bit under Platform Settings:

[image]

Also, change the target platform in Visual Studio in either of the ways:

1. After Opening the .NET 4.8 Web App in Visual Studio 2022, Go to the Build *Menu > Select Configuration Manager > Change Platform* to required bit-configuration:

[image]

OR Right Click on the *.NET 48 Application/Project > Select Properties > Build > Change Platform Value to the required Configuration-bit*:

[image]

Refer [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2022) for more information steps on Configuring the Platform (32-bit/64-bit) for the Visual Studio 2022 Web Application Projects.